# Cancel a ongoing pyrogram upload with an inline button

Tags: python, pyrogram

Well I created a class that is called from main.py

bot is created from a telethon Client, while app is from pyrogram's;

```
class uploader:

    def __init__(self, bot, app):

        self.bot = bot

        self.app = app

        self.is_cancelled = False

    def __str__(self, bot):

        return "#wip"

    async def start(self, from_user_id, filepath, reply, thum, caption, message=""):

        try:

            thum = Path(thum)

            if not thum.is_file():

                thum = None

            async with self.bot.action(from_user_id, "file"):

                await reply.edit("Uploading")

                u_start = time.time()

                if UNLOCK_UNSTABLE and message:

                    s = await message.reply_document(

                        document=filepath,

                        quote=True,

                        thumb=thum,

                        caption=caption,

                        progress=self.progress_for_pyrogram,

                        progress_args=(self.app, "Uploading...", reply, u_start),

                    )

                else:

                    s = await self.app.send_document(

                        document=filepath,

                        chat_id=from_user_id,

                        force_document=True,

                        thumb=thum,

                        caption=caption,

                        progress=self.progress_for_pyrogram,

                        progress_args=(

                            self.app,

                            "Uploading...",

                            reply,

                            u_start,

                        ),

                    )

            return s

        except Exception:

            ers = traceback.format_exc()

            await channel_log(ers)

            LOGS.info(ers)

    async def progress_for_pyrogram(self, current, total, bot, ud_type, message, start):

        now = time.time()

        diff = now - start

        if self.is_cancelled:

            bot.stop_transmission()

            await message.edit_text("`Uploading Cancelled.`")

            return

        if round(diff % 10.00) == 0 or current == total:

            percentage = current * 100 / total

            status = "downloads" + "/status.json"

            if os.path.exists(status):

                with open(status, "r+") as f:

                    statusMsg = json.load(f)

                    if not statusMsg["running"]:

                        bot.stop_transmission()

            speed = current / diff

            time_to_completion = time_formatter(int((total - current) / speed))

            progress = "{0}{1} \n<b>Progress:</b> `{2}%`\n".format(

                "".join(

                    [FINISHED_PROGRESS_STR for i in range(math.floor(percentage / 10))]

                ),

                "".join(

                    [

                        UN_FINISHED_PROGRESS_STR

                        for i in range(10 - math.floor(percentage / 10))

                    ]

                ),

                round(percentage, 2),

            )

            tmp = progress + "`{0} of {1}`\n**Speed:** `{2}/s`\n**ETA:** `{3}`\n".format(

                hbs(current),

                hbs(total),

                hbs(speed),

                # elapsed_time if elapsed_time != '' else "0 s",

                time_to_completion if time_to_completion else "0 s",

            )

            try:

                # Create a "Cancel" button

                cancel_button = InlineKeyboardButton(

                    text="Cancel", callback_data="cancel_upload"

                )

                # Attach the button to the message with an inline keyboard

                reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup([[cancel_button]])

                if not message.photo:

                    await message.edit_text(

                        text="{}\n {}".format(ud_type, tmp),

                        reply_markup=reply_markup,

                    )

                else:

                    await message.edit_caption(

                        caption="{}\n {}".format(ud_type, tmp),

                        reply_markup=reply_markup,

                    )

            except BaseException:

                pass

    @app.on_callback_query()

    async def button_callback(self, callback_query):

        if callback_query.data == "cancel_upload":

            self.is_cancelled = True
```

everything goes well at least there are no errors reported when the cancel button is clicked
But upload doesn't get cancelled

Tried moving button_callback outside of the function but the problem arose from the fact that the function no longer had access to the instance of the class that was uploading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
import uuid

from pyrogram.filters import regex
from pyrogram.handlers import CallbackQueryHandler



class uploader:
    def __init__(self, bot, app, sender=123456):
        self.bot = bot
        self.app = app
        self.sender = int(sender)
        self.callback_data = "cancel_upload" + str(uuid.uuid4())
        self.is_cancelled = False
        self.handler = app.add_handler(
            CallbackQueryHandler(
                self.upload_button_callback, filters=regex("^" + self.callback_data)
            )
        )

    def __str__(self, bot):
        return "#wip"

    async def start(self, from_user_id, filepath, reply, thum, caption, message=""):
        try:
            thum = Path(thum)
            if not thum.is_file():
                thum = None
            async with self.bot.action(from_user_id, "file"):
                await reply.edit("Uploading")
                u_start = time.time()
                if UNLOCK_UNSTABLE and message:
                    s = await message.reply_document(
                        document=filepath,
                        quote=True,
                        thumb=thum,
                        caption=caption,
                        progress=self.progress_for_pyrogram,
                        progress_args=(self.app, "Uploading...", reply, u_start),
                    )
                else:
                    s = await self.app.send_document(
                        document=filepath,
                        chat_id=from_user_id,
                        force_document=True,
                        thumb=thum,
                        caption=caption,
                        progress=self.progress_for_pyrogram,
                        progress_args=(
                            self.app,
                            "Uploading...",
                            reply,
                            u_start,
                        ),
                    )
            self.app.remove_handler(*self.handler)
            return s
        except pyro_errors.BadRequest:
            await reply.edit(f"`Failed {enmoji2()}\nRetrying…`")
            self.app.remove_handler(*self.handler)
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            upload2 = uploader(self.bot, self.app, self.sender)
            await upload2.start(event.chat_id, loc, e, thum, cap, message)

        except Exception:
            self.app.remove_handler(*self.handler)
            ers = traceback.format_exc()
            await channel_log(ers)
            LOGS.info(ers)
            return None

    async def progress_for_pyrogram(self, current, total, app, ud_type, message, start):
        now = time.time()
        diff = now - start
        if self.is_cancelled:
            app.stop_transmission()
        if round(diff % 10.00) == 0 or current == total:
            percentage = current * 100 / total
            status = "downloads" + "/status.json"
            if os.path.exists(status):
                with open(status, "r+") as f:
                    statusMsg = json.load(f)
                    if not statusMsg["running"]:
                        app.stop_transmission()
            speed = current / diff
            time_to_completion = time_formatter(int((total - current) / speed))

            progress = "{0}{1} \n<b>Progress:</b> `{2}%`\n".format(
                "".join(
                    [FINISHED_PROGRESS_STR for i in range(math.floor(percentage / 10))]
                ),
                "".join(
                    [
                        UN_FINISHED_PROGRESS_STR
                        for i in range(10 - math.floor(percentage / 10))
                    ]
                ),
                round(percentage, 2),
            )

            tmp = progress + "`{0} of {1}`\n**Speed:** `{2}/s`\n**ETA:** `{3}`\n".format(
                hbs(current),
                hbs(total),
                hbs(speed),
                # elapsed_time if elapsed_time != '' else "0 s",
                time_to_completion if time_to_completion else "0 s",
            )
            try:
                # Create a "Cancel" button
                cancel_button = InlineKeyboardButton(
                    text="Cancel", callback_data=self.callback_data
                )
                # Attach the button to the message with an inline keyboard
                reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup([[cancel_button]])
                if not message.photo:
                    await message.edit_text(
                        text="{}\n {}".format(ud_type, tmp),
                        reply_markup=reply_markup,
                    )
                else:
                    await message.edit_caption(
                        caption="{}\n {}".format(ud_type, tmp),
                        reply_markup=reply_markup,
                    )
            except BaseException:
                pass

    async def upload_button_callback(self, client, callback_query):
        # if callback_query.data == "cancel_upload":
        if (
            str(callback_query.from_user.id) not in OWNER
            and callback_query.from_user.id != self.sender
        ):
            return await callback_query.answer(
                "You're not allowed to do this!", show_alert=False
            )
        self.is_cancelled = True
        await callback_query.answer("Cancelling upload please wait…", show_alert=False)
```

A better answer would be appreciated though!